# Query to Alter Primary Key to any column with keyword

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with several tables that I am looking to add primary keys to any column with the keyword "KEY" in its name. The first problem that doesn't seem fixable is to run a query against all tables rather than one by one... Secondly I don't see how I can Add Primary key or even drop constraints on wildcard column searches.

For those of you who are visual, this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
ALTER TABLE *
ADD PRIMARY KEY (%KEY%);
```

Keeping in mind SOME tables already have Primary Keys attached, so I may need to Drop Constraints on all first then re-constrain them. If even possible?

Comment: *"run a query against all tables rather than one by one"*  An Access `ALTER TABLE` statement can only target one table.

Comment: Do any of your target tables include an autonumber field whose name does not include "KEY"?  If so, what should happen with those fields?

Comment: It does not. They are all autonumber and are the only columns with the string "Key" in them.

Comment: OK.  It seems like you hoped to do it all with Access DDL, but that's not possible.  You will need DAO to examine the tables in order to identify which must be modified.

Comment: I'm not opposed to VisualBasic. Before I give up is it possible to all add PK to columns containing "KEY" and not specifying the column?

Comment: No, you can't use pattern-matching of a field name in Access DDL; it has to be the literal field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define existing autonumber fields as primary key, consider:

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT fieldname PRIMARY KEY(fieldname)`

However, field cannot already be set with an index and table cannot already have a primary key. Again, use ALTER TABLE to remove index.

`ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT indexname`

Will have to run this SQL for each table that must be modified. If this is a  one-time only requirement (why would it not be?), probably just as fast to open each table and manually modify design.

MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql

The alternative is VBA using TableDefs to modify table structure. Search web for examples.

Comment: I was researching into VBA and might try to piece together something. When I try to drop constraints I get "CHECK constraint 'STOCK_KEY' does not exist. However I can clearly see that this table has the column "STOCK_KEY" as a Primary Key.

`ALTER TABLE STOCK DROP CONSTRAINT STOCK_KEY`

Comment: Well, all I can say is it works for me. Are you sure the field's index has same name?

Comment: Primary key indexes by default have the name `PrimaryKey`, not the field name. Open the table in design view and open the Indexes window. @KevinP.

Comment: It was the correct field name, I had another table selected (was running query in wrong table...)

Comment: @KevinP., okay, yes I see that now. In my test of the ADD CONSTRAINT I assigned field name as the index name because anything else did not work.